# Hibernate embeddables: component property not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to use JPA `@Embeddable`s with Hibernate. The entity and the embeddable both have a property named `id`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
}

@Embeddable
public class B extends A {

}

@Entity
public class C extends A {
    B b;
}
```

This raises a `org.hibernate.MappingException: component property not found: id`.

I want to avoid using `@AttributeOverrides`. I thus tried to set `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy` (I'm using Spring Boot). This did not have any effect (same exception). I, however, suspect that the setting is beeing ignored because specifying a non-existing class doesn't raise an exception.

The strange thing is, even with this variant

```
@Entity
public class C extends A {
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="id", column = @Column(name="b_id") ),
    } )
    B b;
}
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The naming strategy configuration has changed. The new way as per the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties) is this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl
```

Also, you must not use `@Id` within an `@Embeddable`. I thus created a seperate `@MappedSuperclass` for embeddables:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class E {
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
}

@Embeddable
public class B extends E {

}

@Entity
public class C extends A {
    B b;
}
```

This way, the table `C` has two columns `id` and `b_id`. The downside is of course that `A` and `E` introduce some redundency. Comments regarding a DRY approach to this are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This conflict can occurs when your Embeddable class has also Id column.
Then try to remove Id field from class with @Embeddable.