# Map JPA Embedded entity class id to Embeddable entity class id

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, microservices, hibernate-mapping

I have a class:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "b_id"))
    private B b;
}
```

There is column b_id BIGINT NOT NULL in table A

```
@Embeddable
@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

we are getting error: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component property not found: id

Basically, we need to map B in A using id

Kindly help

Comment: On which class are you having your exception? Is your column from `class B` actually named `id` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate embeddables: component property not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040315/hibernate-embeddables-component-property-not-found)

Comment: @DamCx Yes class B has column name id

Comment: @SergVasylchak ...Tried this is not working

Comment: I think `B` shouldn't be annotated with `@Entity`, only `@Embeddable`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with `@Id` in embedded class. We can not use in an embedded class. Try removing that? If you can remove it, try using `@EmbeddedId` if you just need an id field.

Comment: We need to map two Entity classes and hence @Id is mandatory. we cannot remove it

Comment: I understand why you cant remove it. But that's how it is! You can have @Id.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    @Entity
    public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9154946919235019012L;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "b_id"))
    private B b;
    public A() {
    }

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }


    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    }
```

And here is class B

```
@Embeddable
@Entity

public class B implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5579181803793008928L;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    public B(Long id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public B(){

    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    }
```

You don't have getters and setters, or an additional constructor besides the implicit no arg one. You should have both a no-args constructor and getter and setter methods.