# Hibernate Java configuration spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, config

Hi I am trying to make Java configuration for hibernate from application.properties but the code execution gives the following error.
I am getting mapping error but I checked everything my mapping is correct.It says an id is not while creating ***sessionFactory*** bean.
I have tried to correct but I am not able to please help.

Here is my DBConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class DBConfig {

@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
public String driver;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
public String url;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
public String username;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
public String password;

@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
public String dialect;

@Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
public String ddl;

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    return dataSource;
}


@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernateSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.abc.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

//Hibernate Transaction
@Bean 
HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory((SessionFactory) hibernateSessionFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}



@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
   return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
       {
          setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",ddl);
          setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode","true");
          setProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto",ddl);
          setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
          setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect",dialect);
          setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
          setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8mb4");
          setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");

       }
    };
 }
}
```

When I try to run this I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component property not found: id
at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getProperty(Component.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2779) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2620) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2568) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2197) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
... 32 common frames omitted
```

Comment: check this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/39117563/4828463 it seems similar

Comment: @FarazDurrani yes I already tried this way but it is still now working.

Comment: Why are you doing this? In SpringBoot configuring the `spring.datasource` properties will autoconfigure a ready to go data source?

Comment: @Strelok actaully I am migrating from older spring version with spring-dispatcher.xml so I need to create sessionFactory and Datasource beans which are being used further in the code.

Comment: But if you're "using" SpringBoot it will be auto configured for you already.

Comment: @Strelok yes it will be autoconfigured but I need to create session factory to run an old code so is there a way in spring to configure sessionFactory bean without using datasource bean and not get this mapping error?

Comment: Fixed the issue thanks for the help.