# How to insert multiple records with JPA repositories in a table with a composed PK and one of it is auto incremented?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm building a controller with spring boot to store a list of records, but the table where the records will be stored has a composed PK (two fields) and one of the fields of the composition is auto_incrementable, my entities are defined as follow:

**TaskPK.java**

```java
@Embeddable
public class TaskPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="taskflow_template_task_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer taskflowTemplateTaskId;

    @Column(name="taskflow_template_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer taskflowTemplateId;

// Getters, setters and constructors
}
```

In this PK the taskflowTemplateTaskId is an AI field

**Task.java**

```java
public class Task extends BaseEntity implements Serializable, Persistable<TaskPK> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TaskPK id = new TaskPK();

    @Column(name="task_id")
    private Integer taskId;

    @Column(name="display_order", nullable=false)
    private int displayOrder;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TaskflowTemplate
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="taskflow_template_id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private TaskflowTemplate taskflowTemplate;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return (id.getTaskflowTemplateTaskId() == null || id.getTaskflowTemplateId() == null);
    }
```

The task entity has a spring data JPA repositories associated without any custom queries

Finally, this is the code i'm using to store the data, is a simple function called from the controller

```java
@Transactional
public void createTask(List<Task> tasks){
    taskRepository.saveAll(tasks)
}
```

And the data I'm receiving is represented in the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "displayOrder": 1,
    "taskId": 1,
    "id": {
        "taskflowTemplateId" : "1"
     }
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": 2,
    "taskId": 2,
    "id": {
        "taskflowTemplateId" : "1"
     }
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": 3,
    "taskId": 3,
    "id": {
        "taskflowTemplateId" : "1"
     }
  }
]
```

When i run this code i get this exception

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.test.taskmaster.entity.Task#TaskPK(taskflowTemplateTaskId=null, taskflowTemplateId=1)]
```

So, I'm guessing the field taskflowTemplateTaskId is not being generated by hibernate, instead it is sending as null. When only one record is created this works well because the null is replaced on database by the AI field, but when i try to insert a list of records all with null taskflowTemplateTaskId because i want it to be generated, that error happens.

I've tried using save inside a loop, and saveAndFlush without success, also i've tried different type of GenerationType and even using @Generated(GenerationTime).

Comment: Why you make insertable = false in that field.

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 because the taskflow_template_id is used in a relationship, thus the field is representend more than once and it's required for it to be insertable = false, i updated my question to reflect that relationship

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to save multiple rows in your table with the reference to the same object.

```
@Column(name="taskflow_template_task_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer taskflowTemplateTaskId;
```

to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="taskflow_template_task_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer taskflowTemplateTaskId;
```

Comment: After making this  change the app doesn't compile, it gives the following error: `org.hibernate.MappingException: component property not found: taskflowTemplateTaskId`. I think is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39117563)